# Callback Method return undefined for Google people API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-api, callback

I want to get all Google contacts data in API. I am using two functions to get data and return that data in API.
API name /contacts
I am getting undefined data in the Contacts function. But in listconnection() there is all data.

```
/*
* 
*
* @return JSON ARRAY
*/
app.get('/contacts',  function(req, res){
  
  // Load client secrets from a local file.
  fs.readFile('credentials.json', async (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Tasks API.
      let allcontact =   authorize(JSON.parse(content), listConnectionNames);
      console.log(allcontact);
      return allcontact;
  });

})
```

I am using two more function to get data in contacts.

```
/**
 * Create an   with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
 function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
     return  callback(oAuth2Client);
      
  });
}
```

Get all contacts via listconnection.

```
/**
 * Print the display name if available for 10 connections.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listConnectionNames(auth) {
  const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth});
  service.people.connections.list({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    pageSize: 50,
    personFields: 'names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const connections = res.data.connections;
    if (connections) {
      return connections;

    } else {
      console.log('No connections found.');
    }
  });
}
```

IF someone can help me on this